# How to Edit InfoPath Form Web Part embedded into a page when there is no list associated with the Form?

Tags: web-part, infopath, form, edit

I'm having difficulty editing a SharePoint 2010 page. Someone else created it. The set up is a bit different than normal. The page has an InfoPath form embedded in to it. I have full admin rights to the site, so I should be able to do anything. When I click on Edit on the ribbon and go into page edit mode, all I see are two web parts, **InfoPath Form Web Part [ 1]** and **InfoPath Form Web Part [2]**. Here is an image of what I see:

[image]
Please note: I **cannot see any sign that this page or the web parts are associated with a list**. I tried playing around with the web part properties, and the ribbon features, but I cannot find any way to make actual edits. For example to open the form in InfoPath and make edits. There is **no List tab, or Lists and Libraries option.**

Does anyone have any ideas what I can do to edit the page? My goal is to be able to alter the content of the web parts.